# Apple Production Push Service is not working!

Tags: php, ssl, apple-push-notifications

Please, help me! I've tried intensely to find the answer to my problem but I was unsuccessful all the time.

I've implemented the Development Push Notification successfully for my app, but when submitted the app and updated the code to the Production service I can't send the push notification.
I have no errors on sending at all, but the push notifications are not being received by the registered devices.

The php code for in my server is something like this:

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create();

stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'apns-dev.pem');

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, 15, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

if (!$apns)
{
echo "ERROR";
} else 
{
    if ($error)
    {
        echo "ERROR: " . $error . ": " . $errorString;
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "<p> Processing....</p><br />";
        $inputMessage = utf8_encode($_POST['text']);
        echo "<p>MESSAGE: $inputMessage</p>";
        $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $inputMessage, 'sound' => 'default');

        $payload = json_encode($payload);

        $apnsMessagePart1 = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32);
        $apnsMessagePart3 = chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        $xml = simplexml_load_file("tokens.xml");   

        if ($xml != NULL) {
            $devicesCount = 0;
            foreach($xml->children() as $deviceToken)
            {
                echo "<p>processando aparelho com o token: $deviceToken</p>";
                $apnsMessagePart2 = pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken));
                $apnsMessage = $apnsMessagePart1 . $apnsMessagePart2 . $apnsMessagePart3;
                $success = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
                if (!$success)
                    echo "Error sending message to $deviceToken";
                else
                    $devicesCount++;
            }
            socket_close($apns);
            fclose($apns);
            echo "<h2>... done!</h2>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h4>error: no xml file found!</h4>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the same device token for development and production? The tokens for the two services are separate and not interchangeable.

Answer (score 15):

You can check two things

- You are using the production certificate and not development certificate
- The device tokens list doesn't have any device id which was generated by a development build. If you try to send a notification to a development device token with production certificate apple will just drop the connection silently and none of the tokens after that will receive the notifications.

Comment: Thank you for your second note there. I hadn't noticed that anywhere in the documentation. I'd been sending notifications to all of the tokens. There were only a couple of development tokens in the database but I figured they'd be ignored. No foul, right? WRONG. Again, thanks.

Comment: Just stumbed across this as well. Nasty. Would be nicer if they'd just report invalid tokens using the feedback service so there can be cleanup work afterwards. Also APNS didn't drop the connection. No errors reported.

Comment: +1 for your second point.  I didn't realize that the development environment has a different device ID than the production environment.

Comment: "If you try to send a notification to a development device token with production certificate apple will just drop the connection silently and none of the tokens after that will receive the notifications." - That is crucial information that fixed my problem. Thanks!